# R command file.path

Tags: r

```
file.path('folder1','folder2')
#[1] "folder1/folder2"
```

What did command above do within my working directory?
The response: `[1] "folder1/folder2"` is unclear

Comment: Have you read the help file `?file.path`

Comment: You may want `path.expand` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't do anything with your working directory; it makes the path and then you have to assign it to working directory:

```
> file.path('C:','Users')  
[1] "C:/Users"  
> getwd()  
[1] "C:/Users/T/Documents"  
> setwd(file.path('C:','Users'))  
> getwd()  
[1] "C:/Users"
```